# Retrieve a Customized String Value

Tags: c#

Goal:
Retrieve a string value that is "1_2_3" om the code myListAnimals. In the future, the value can be random. 
I need to add a "_" between numbers.

Problem:
I don't know how to do it by using LINQ?

```
public class Animal
{
    private void int _number;
    private void string _name;
    private bool display;


    public int Number
    {
        get { return _number;}
            set { _number = value; }
        }

    public int Name
    {
        get { return _name;
            set { _name = value; }
        }

    public bool Display
    {
        get { return display;
            set { display = value; }
        }

}


List<Animal> myListAnimal = new List<Animal>

Animal myAnimal = new List<Animal>
myAnimal.Number = 1;
myAnimal.Name = "Dog";
myAnimal.Display = True;

myAnimals.add(myAnimal )


Animal myAnimal2 = new List<Animal>
myAnimal2.Number = 2;
myAnimal2.Name = "Cat";
myAnimal2.Display = True;

myAnimals.add(myAnimal2)


Animal myAnimal3 = new List<Animal>
myAnimal3.Number = 3;
myAnimal3.Name = "Pig";
myAnimal3.Display = True;  

myAnimals.add(myAnimal3)

Animal myAnimal4 = new List<Animal>
myAnimal4.Number = 4;
myAnimal4.Name = "Sheep";
myAnimal4.Display = false;      

myAnimals.add(myAnimal4)
```

Comment: your code sample isn't valid c#

Comment: BrokenGlass - I wrote the code directly in the notepad.

Comment: @JeffreyZhang That's a strong assertion to make

Comment: @jdphenix, I'm sorry for that, But i think it's diffcult to implement use linq because it require the value can be random

Answer (score 1):

Note: Your code sample isn't valid C#. I assume that you can fix that (it's pretty simple basic changes that need to be made). That said:

Yes, you can use LINQ to concatenate strings, which is ultimately what you're doing.

```
var concat = myListAnimal
    .Where(a => a.Display)
    .Select(a => a.Number.ToString())
    .Aggregate((current, next) => current + "_" + next);

Console.WriteLine(concat);
```

Would output with your data:

```
1_2_3
```

- `Where()` filters the values where `Display != true`
- `Select()` projects the number values to a sequence of strings
- and `Aggregate()` does the concatenation.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `StringBuilder` and `ForEach` extension method.

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(); 
myAnimals.ForEach(x=> sb.AppendFormat("{0}_",x.Number));
```

Answer (score 0):

your code is not valid. First fix it and try this.

```
var concat =string.Join("_", myListAnimal.Select(a => a.Number).ToArray());
```